# xforms dynamic dropdown autocomplete/autoinsert

Tags: java, rest, orbeon, xforms

Based on the field value (eg - 1,2,3,...) of the **xml_my_field**, through the REST service, I receive dropdown list options to choose in my dynamic dropdown. Options are the same as the **xml_my_field** value (1,2,3,...). REST service generate xml like this:

```
<item>
    <label>name1</label>
    <value>1</value>
</item>
<item>
    <label>name2</label>
    <value>2</value>
</item>
```

Is there any possibility, when I have only one value (eg - 1 or 2) in  my **xml_my_field**, to automatically insert this to my dropdown field, not only in dropdown options, but auto fill field? Here is my itemset:

```
<fr:databound-select1 xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
    xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
    id="xml_dropdown_field-control"
    appearance="minimal"
    resource="http://wfw-forms:8080/workflow/seam/resource/restv1/podmiotNumber/getPodmiot?numerPodmiotu={//xml_my_field}"
    bind="xml_dropdown_field-bind">
    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/xml_dropdown_field/label" xh:style=""/>
    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/xml_dropdown_field/hint"/>
    <xf:help ref="$form-resources/xml_dropdown_field/help"/>
    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
    <xf:itemset ref="item">
        <xf:label ref="label"/>
        <xf:value ref="value"/>
    </xf:itemset>       
</fr:databound-select1>
```

I try to add to my **fr:databound-select1** something like this, but it seems to not working

```
<xforms:action ev:event="fr-search-changed">
    <xxforms:variable name="search-value" select="event(//xml_my_field)"/>
    <xxforms:variable name="make-suggestion" select="string-length($search-value) = 1"/>
    <xforms:action if="$make-suggestion">
        <xforms:setvalue ref="xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//xml_dropdown_field"      value="$search-value"/>
    </xforms:action>
</xforms:action>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to solve this by using xpath expression in **calculate** attribute. This gave me the opportunity to autamic insert the value and do not disturb my REST functionality.